# Which router should I buy for 3G/HSDPA using Three Mobile Ireland?

Tags: router, 3g, broadband

I've been spending quite a bit of time working over in the Republic of Ireland (Co. Donegal) at the moment. There's no terrestrial ADSL but there is a fairly usable 3G/HSDPA service from Three Mobile Ireland.

I'm wondering if there are any StackOverflow users that reside in the Republic of Ireland who are using Three Mobile's [3G 3Pay mobile broadband service](http://www.three.ie/broadband/3pay.htm) with either a [Billion 3G router](http://www.billion.uk.com/product/3g.htm) (the 7402NX or 7402GX/GXL) or the [Dovado UMR](http://www.dovado.com/UMR.html)? If so, does the Huawei E160G dongle work with these products without any problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should buy a single device and without USB. I am
using the same company ("3"), but not in Ireland, and I am
using [Ericsson’s W21 3G Router](http://www.ericssonw21.com/). There is nothing to
install on the client computer: this router has 4 normal
Ethernet outputs and wireless (WLAN/Wireless LAN IEEE
802.11b/g.). It is also more secure.

I have used this device for nearly 2 years and it works
great. For my marginal geographical location I get up to 1.5
MBit/s. The only gotcha is that 2G should be disabled;
otherwise it will switch to 2G when 3G falls out for a brief
moment and stay there until a power cycle...

(This answer has been sent through the W21...)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I didn't think I'd see one so quickly. The Ericsson looks ace and the tool for the job, but I'm on a budget of max GBP160.00. Where did you buy yours?

Comment: I bought it at the same time as the original subscription (from the "3" company). But as far as I know they no longer sell the W21. Perhaps there is a similar less costly device from another manufacturer (?).

Comment: I've hunted high and low. I think I'll suck it and see with the Billion 7402NX :)

Comment: I bought the Billion 7402NX, works a treat. Also didn't notice the Draytek 2800 I have in Scotland supports 3G dongles. Could've saved some money but at least the place in Ireland is WiFi enabled now.

Comment: Product page for Billion BiPAC 7402NX: http://www.billion.com/product/3g/bipac7402nx-wireless-11n-3G-ADSL2-vpn-firewall-router.html